# Connected graph reduction problem

Tags: graph-theory

Graph Theory Problem 3 - please help

> Prove that for any connected graph $G$ there is a vertex $v$ of $G$ such that $G−v$ is still connected

Comment: Please show us any work you have attempted for this problem, to allow a response at a suitable level of detail.

Comment: I tried different ways to approach connectivity. I am still having problems to start my proof. If I deattach a vertex from a connected graph I still see connectivity unless I end up having a trivial graph. But my idea is that of removing a vertex and still reaching connectivity. At the end a point can still be connected to itself. I presume???

Comment: A graph of one vertex is connected, yes, even though it has no edges.

Comment: Would that end the proof?

Comment: I guess it could do so, depending on your proof. But there is no need to reduce the graph to a single vertex.

Comment: @ExoPrimes Hallo Exo, I encourage you to choose a correct answer and accept it as it is the culture of MathStackExchange

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is connected, then you can have a spanning $T$ tree in $G$. Then, you can delete a leaf $v$ of $T$.